# Language-bar keyboard layout (not language) missing after Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, language-bar

I have two keyboards on my Windows 10 machine, one UK and one US, both are setup for English US language like this:

[image: Keyboards]

In a recent Windows update the keyboard indication disappeared and does not show any more which is really annoying:

[image: Language bar]

It used to include the keyboard layout and would look something like below even when I had configured the taskbar with "small taskbar buttons":

[image: Keyboards old behaviour]

**Question**: Can I get back the old behaviour without using the space wasting large taskbar buttons?

I have Windows 10 Enterprise version 1511 with OS build 10586.1176

**Similar questions**

[Display keyboard layout on the language bar in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1248490/display-keyboard-layout-on-the-language-bar-in-windows-10): This question asks for a solution for a similar question. The difference is I'm asking how to see the keyboard layout without using the large taskbar buttons

Comment: Could you try the following?  1) Try to install one more keyboard, pick a random one.  2) Could you try pressing Windows key + space does anything appear?

Answer (score 0):

As tukan said, add a random keyboard under

- Settings,
- Time & Language ,
- Language,
- Pick a preferred language,
- Click options
- Click Add Keyboard
- You can remove it immediately after having added it.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 21H2 I found that the taskbar would only indicate the language and the keyboard layout if the taskbar has sufficient height relative to the size of the text to show two lines.  Unlocking the taskbar and resizing it to be taller will allow the keyboard layout indicator to fit, as does reducing the display scale setting, or turning off "Use small taskbar buttons" in taskbar settings.

If those options are unacceptable, you can work around this problem by installing your second keyboard layout under the Anglo-Saxon language, which it shows as "ANG".  The Anglo-Saxon language doesn't come with spellcheckers or other features, but in practice I don't find this to be a limitation.  I also changed the input language hot keys so that Ctrl+Shift would switch between input languages instead of switching keyboard layouts.  Don't use a different English language as your second language, because unhelpfully, these are all indicated as "ENG" in the taskbar.